# How to cache firebase function result?

Tags: firebase, caching, google-cloud-functions

I've a firebase function that is calling a web API for which I'm billed per request. I would like to cache the result of the firebase function for each set of parameters. Especially because some webclient may request exactly the same request several times.

Is there a way to configure a firebase function to cache result? Or should I use firestore to "manually" cache this call?

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration in the Firebase client-side SDKs to cache calls to/results from Cloud Functions, but it should be pretty easy to build this yourself for both Callable and HTTP Functions.

Same for the server-side code: no caching is built in, but you can typically easily  build it on top - as long as you keep in mind that Cloud Functions containers are spun up and down regularly.

Comment: okay, so server-side, saving a document for each request with a key being a concatenation of the parameters could work? Or is there something smarter to do?

Comment: That would work. You can write it to the `/tmp` drive (which is backed by your Cloud Functions RAM). That way it *may* be there when there's another invocation.

Comment: The would work - unless your supplier returns the same result for the given input parameters over time.
In terms of a `/tmp` directory - I personally would not use it trying to store the data between cloud function invocations, as - it may be empty in case of a ‘cold start’ or/and you have time periods without invocations at all.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've implemented something and I'm currently testing it, I will post the full implementation once done. Just have to finish the "cache cleanup" part

Comment: @J4N And, did you get anywhere with this by now?